# Pointers on implementation of Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-7, network-programming

I've started playing with sockets and have started on a small game for testing purposes. The server is asynchronous and it's working good, but not great, so i'm looking for pointers from people who've gotten good results in their apps.

**Scenario:**
In the app i'm connecting to the server in Application_Launching/Application_Activated and disconnecting in Application_Closing/Application_Deactivated. 
I noticed that in the "Tic-Tac-Toe Over Sockets Sample" on MSDN they're closing the socket on the server every time when data has been sent to the app and connecting every time before data is sent from the app to the server.

**Discussion:**
Do people prefer to manage the connections in the app lifecycle events? It seems rather odd to open/close the sockets for each operation, like they do in the samples. Seems to nullify the advantages of using sockets in the 1st place.

**Scenario:**
Let's say we're implementing some sort of matchmaking method, which is relatively long-running. Let's use 20 seconds as an example.

**Discussion:**
When the client asks for an opponent, would you prefer to loop the client list and sleep periodically until a suitable opponent has been found? Or would you recommend just adding the client to a pool of clients looking for opponents and loop through this periodically in a separate thread?

Bottom line is that if someone has successfully implemented a Windows Phone app/game using sockets i would love to get info on how you handled things like:

- Connection lifecycle
- Long-running operations on the server
- Clients quitting the app at "any time", including when doing long-running operations on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the open/close:

MSDN sample in which it closes the socket after each operation is a neat practical method which most people might use. however there is no *right way* in socket programming. in fact there are a lot!

About threading:

- If you're using (synchronous) blocking methods such as `Listen` then loop and sleep is a bad idea. you can't *cancel* a blocking method.
- If you're using (asynchronous) non-blocking methods such as `BeginSend` or `BeginListen` 
  then threading is not needed.

Comment: About opening/closing the sockets: Closing the sockets seems impractical when you want to send something to the client without the client initiating the "conversation". About threading: Yes, i'm using the non-blocking versions (BeginX/EndX) without any additional threading at the moment. I was thinking about the matchmaking scenario there. If it's best to loop the client list (with some sleeping) in the BeginReceive callback until a suitable opponent has been found or just mark them as "looking for an opponent" and then have a separate thread which handles the matchmaking.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the details of your question. In this case I think all clients can be connected to the server, but their connections should remain opened. when a matching opponent is found, send a message through its corresponding socket (and then close it). If the client are also using non-blocking methods then they hold their sockets open knowing that they're in a waiting state until they got the message. And for the threading issue I would use a single thread (lobby) looping through awaiting clients. I think the combination of these two approaches grants you more options.

Comment: For the game itself, you'll need to figure out a way that all clients always start conversations not the server. this way you can close the socket after each conversation. you can of-course leave the socket open till the end of the game. but in my experience in sockets, short in duration and more in numbers is much easier to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll create a branch in my CVS and go nuts, with your suggestions in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

For good examples of asynchronous socket programming checkout the open source network communication library, [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net).

Comment: Thanks, i've looked briefly at it before and will read more later. BUT, the biggest problem is handling the client-side (phone) gracefully, which can "tombstone" the app at any time, resume later, navigate back and forth between views. Handling this in a good way and notifying opponents is giving me a headache at the moment.